# How to set value of a private constant in class dynamically?

Tags: php, class

I want to set value of a private constant in a class by a get parameter value or posted parameter value but have no success.
It's Google Ads Api script sample:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

```
//$cid = $_GET["cid"];

class GetCampaigns
{
    
    private const CUSTOMER_ID = "1234567890";
    
    public static function main()
    {
        // Either pass the required parameters for this example on the command line, or insert them
        // into the constants above.
        $options = (new ArgumentParser())->parseCommandArguments([
            ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID => GetOpt::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT
        ]);

.....
```

Comment: A constant can't be set dynamically, it has to be set to a literal.

Comment: It's variable not constant so why use a constant?  That aside, how would `$cid` get into the class?